# Similar WPF Windows

Tags: wpf, windows, stack, panel

I have WPF Application and 2 Windows with similar structure (everything is same:menu, Title, Toolbar, only in the middle one stack panel is other, in one window has 10 TextFields,Button and other controls,and other one has other controls in this stack panel.I can copy one window in other, but I duplicate code.How can i solve this problem?Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a `ControlTemplate` and/or `Style` for the Window.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyWindowTemplate" TargetType="Window">
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <DockPanel>
            <!-- Your toolbar content and other shared content -->

            <!-- The dynamic content is loaded into the content presenter: -->
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />

        </DockPanel>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyWindowTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

When you now create a window instance, you apply the style to the window and add some content into the content property and (if necessary) some ContentTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Create just one window and:

1. Add all the common controls required for both the screens.
2. Add the different stack panels in the same place and bind their visibility to the same flag.
3. Implement the InverseBooleanConverter and bind that to one of the stack panel's visibility based on how you are going to handle the flag.
4. Handle the flag before launching the view i.e. set it to true or false based on which window you are showing at that time.

Comment: I don't have only 2 windows, probably later i would have 5-6 Windows.Can I define integer variable and bind that with stack panels?

Comment: Where are these stack panels define? I use dock panel and fill them and then at the end I have only one stack panel.But this one can be one of 5-6 stack panels

Comment: The controls which are not common should be put inside a parent panel. It could be a dock panel or stack panel or a grid. The parent panel's visibility property will be bound to the flag. For example: The controls that are different will be in grid's 1st row and 2nd column, then you will have two different panel's in that particular cell and their visibility will be based on the flag. If you have 5-6 windows, then use a enumeration and a switch case and handle all the control inside it.

Comment: Do this only if major of the control's are common. Else either create different windows or use a master page with all the common controls and load the child view's inside the master page.